# how to use flutter in youtube api

Tags: flutter, youtube-api

I'm playing the video using YouTube api on the plotter, and using that method, there's a problem with the video sync.
Is there any way to correct this error?
I downloaded the video and voice separately and am using it because of the quality problem.

Answer (score 0):

i was using this package :
[youtubevideo player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_youtube)

Comment: Does this package synchronize the video and voice well?

Comment: yes it's working for me as it should...playing videos in application both android and ios

Comment: i use package = youtube_explode_dart: ^1.0.0

Comment: I need to use this package, can't I solve it with that package?

Comment: whats the error msg or issue showing?? can i get some code snippet for more details

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't show you the code.
The content of the issue that I have is that the video and audio are out of sync.
In order to control the quality of the video, I download the video and voice separately and show them together, but sometimes they are out of sync or they are out of sync at the same time in front and back.